# Proving $ \sum\limits^{n}_{i=m}a_i+\sum\limits^{p}_{i=n+1}a_i=\sum\limits^{p}_{i=m}a_i $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, induction

Prove that  :

> Let $m\leq n<p$ be integers and let $a_i$ be a real number assigned to each integer $m\leq i\leq p$. Then we have
>   $$\sum\limits^{n}_{i=m}a_i+\sum\limits^{p}_{i=n+1}a_i=\sum\limits^{p}_{i=m}a_i $$

I am following analysis 1 by Tao. He defines series recursively. So we cannot use 
$$\sum\limits^{n}_{i=m}a_i = a_m+a_{m+1} \cdots+a_n$$ Here we should use (according to me) induction or  backward induction. But in proof by induction I am stuck at the following problem regarding base case $$a_m+ \sum\limits^{p}_{i=m+1}a_i $$.
I had similar problem when I tried backward induction.
How to get past this ?

Comment: Try reversing the induction. Put the summation on the left and induce on the number of terms on the right.

Comment: This is not a series (unless you consider it as one with only finitely many nonzero terms.) It's just a finite sum. I may be missing something, but we know that the real numbers are an ordered field, so one can handle this with properties of associativity.

Comment: @RSerrao we will easily get the base case but how to prove that if $ \sum\limits^{n}_{i=m}a_i+\sum\limits^{p}_{i=n+1}a_i=\sum\limits^{p}_{i=m}a_i$ is true then $\sum\limits^{n-1}_{i=m}a_i+\sum\limits^{p}_{i=n}a_i=\sum\limits^{p}_{i=m}a_i $ is also true. Here we face the same problem. We can get a term outside the summation inside if its the last term. If its the first term then we are in trouble.

Comment: in your base case, $m=n$, does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing your induction from the wrong end. First prove that $\sum_{i=m}^na_i + \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+1}a_i = \sum_{i=m}^{n+1}a_i$ (this should be straightforward from your recursive definition). Then, supposing that $\sum_{i=m}^na_i + \sum_{i=n+1}^pa_i = \sum_{i=m}^pa_i$, show that $\sum_{i=m}^na_i + \sum_{i=n+1}^{p+1}a_i = \sum_{i=m}^{p+1}a_i$. For that, use your recursive definition for $\sum$ on the *second* summation, not the first.

Comment: Observation: The key here is to induct on $p$ not $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add this because its cute;

$$\sum\limits^{n}_{i=m}a_i+\sum\limits^{p}_{i=n+1}a_i=\sum\limits^{p}_{i=m}a_i$$
$$\sum\limits^{n}_{i=m}a_i+a_{n+1}+\sum\limits^{p}_{i=n+2}a_i=\sum\limits^{p}_{i=m}a_i$$
$$\sum\limits^{n+1}_{i=m}a_i+\sum\limits^{p}_{i=n+2}a_i=\sum\limits^{p}_{i=m}a_i$$

Answer (score 0):

Write:

$$\sum\limits_{i=m}^p a_i = a_m+a_{m+1}+ \cdots+a_p$$

Then place an imaginary vertical bar through any plus sign to get your result.

Comment: Can we do that ? Tao says writing a series like written above is less formal.

Comment: if you take the dots out it's not

Comment: But $p$ is not known. So how can we take the dots out.