# Rearranging finite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a recursive definition of finite sum: 
$$\sum_{i=m}^n a_i := 0, n<m;$$
$$ \sum_{i=m}^{n+1} a_i := (\sum_{a_m}^n a_i) + a_{n+1}, n\geq m-1.$$

I am trying to show

$$\sum_{i=m}^n a_i + \sum_{i=n+1}^p a_i = \sum_{i=m}^p a_i. $$

I proceed by induction, with

$$P(n): \sum_{i=m}^n a_i + \sum_{i=n+1}^p a_i = \sum_{i=m}^p a_i $$

starting at

$$P(m-1): \sum_{i=m}^{m-1} a_i + \sum_{i=m-1+1}^p a_i = \sum_{i=m}^p a_i $$

Then to show $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$, show

$$P(n): \sum_{i=m}^{n+1} a_i + \sum_{i=n+2}^p a_i = \sum_{i=m}^p a_i .$$

We have

$$\sum_{i=m}^{n+1} a_i + \sum_{i=n+2}^p a_i$$
$$=\sum_{i=m}^na_i + a_{n+1} + \sum_{i=n+2}^p a_i$$

Is there a way to finish this path?

---

This problem is approached differently in another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2005093/255787).

Comment: In your first line, do you actually mean $n>m$ ?

Comment: @Evargalo I don't think so

Comment: Well, then your question doesn't make sense. But if you're ready in reverse the inequality, have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004842/proving-sum-limitsn-i-ma-i-sum-limitsp-i-n1a-i-sum-limitsp-i?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I linked that post in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I'd overlooked that you already referred to that link.

Comment: Oh wait, forget about all that. - Sorry